# Array index as property

Tags: javascript

How can you prove that an array’s indices are just the enumerable properties? I know, it shows up during a `for in` *loop*, but what I mean is: how can I prove that an array’s index is a property? And also an enumerable property?

Are they identical to general Object properties?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean... `Object.getOwnPropertyNames([1, 2]); // ["0", "1", "length"]`?

Comment: `Object.propertyIsEnumerable()`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/propertyIsEnumerable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prove it’s an enumerable property pretty easily. As you said, it shows up in a `for in` loop. That’s the definition of “enumerable”. If you want another way, though:

```
var a = ['hello'];

Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(a, '0')

// {value: 1, writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: true}
```

And yes, they’re like any other object property, except for that they change an array’s `length` if one past the end is created. That’s the only different thing about arrays.

```
var a = [];
a[0] = 5;
a.length // 1
```

Comment: @mminitech Thank u ,that was helpful.Can i assume that all the names used under [] and with . operator are properties

Comment: @Maizere: Yup! That’s what they’re there for.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly, yes, array indices are effectively the same as object properties. When you set the property of an object, the internal [`[[DefineOwnProperty]]`](http://es5.github.io/#x8.12.9) function runs. The specification gives a [modified version](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.5.1) of that function that is used when dealing with Array objects.

After various checks (to ensure the property identifier is a valid array index for example), it does the following:

> 5. Return the result of calling the default [[DefineOwnProperty]] internal method (8.12.9) on A passing *P*, *Desc*, and *Throw* as arguments

Which is exactly what happens for "normal" objects.